# JPA. Bidirectional association: ManyToOne. How to remove association when parent is removed?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have two entities: `Product` and `Category`

```
  public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade =  CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<Product> products;
}

public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id")
    private Category category;
}
```

I want to keep my childs (products) in db (with the value of `category` equal to `null`)  after removing the parent (category).
Currently, when I try to delete a category, I get this error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "CONSTRAINT_F2: PUBLIC.PRODUCTS FOREIGN KEY(CATEGORIES_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CATEGORIES(ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before deleting the category you need to update the association.
For example:

```
Category category = ...
for (Product p : category.getProducts()) {
   p.setCategory(null);
}
category.getProducts().clear();
entityManager.remove(category);
```

Comment: OK, but is this `clear()` necessary? Without it, I also achieve my goal

Comment: The documentation states:"Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times."  (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional). So, yes.